# How do I write the equivalent of Spring's jee:jndi-lookup in Grails resources.groovy?

Tags: spring, grails

I want to take something like this that works ok in Grails' resource.xml (standard Spring xml stuff):

```
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="remoteConnectionFactory"
    jndi-name="jms/WLQueueConnectionFactory" resource-ref="false">
       <jee:environment>
           java.naming.factory.initial=weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory
           java.naming.provider.url=t3://remote_uri:port/
       </jee:environment>
 </jee:jndi-lookup>
```

and turn it into Grails bean builder DSL in resources.groovy. I've tried the combination of the following (basically trial and error to see if I could get it to work, none do):

```
ejbJndi(JndiTemplate)
{ bean ->
    bean.scope = 'session'
    environment = [
        "java.naming.provider.url" : "t3://remote_uri:port/",
        "java.naming.factory.initial" : "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory"
    ]
}
xmlns jee:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
xmlns context:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"

jee.'jndi-lookup'(id:"jmsConnectionFactory", jndiName: "com.retailexp.jms.ConnectionFactory", lookupOnStartup: false,
    proxyInterface: "javax.jms.ConnectionFactory", resourceRef: "false", 'jndi-environment': ref("ejbJndi")) {
    cache = true
    exposeAccessContext = true

    jndiTemplate = ref("ejbJndi")
    jndiEnvironment = [
        "java.naming.provider.url" : "t3://remote_uri:port/",
        "java.naming.factory.initial" : "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory"
    ] as Properties

    environmentRef = [
        "java.naming.provider.url" : "t3://remote_uri:port/",
        "java.naming.factory.initial" : "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory"
    ]

    environment = """
        java.naming.provider.url=t3://remote_uri:port/
        java.naming.factory.initial=weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory
"""
```

Again, these are combinations of things I've tried, not what the final code would look like (I'd hope just one of these would work!). As you can tell I'm groping in the dark a bit.

The jndi-lookup is set up ok and is valid bean DSL, but the environment (JndiTemplate type stuff) does not have the values (java.naming.factory.initial etc) I'm setting to grab the remote InitialContext.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an XML namespace you will need the following at the top of your Grails 'beans' definitions:

```
beans {
    xmlns context:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns jee:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"

    context.'property-placeholder'('location':'classpath:config.properties')
    jee.'jndi-lookup'(id:"jmsConnectionFactory", jndiName: "com.retailexp.jms.ConnectionFactory", lookupOnStartup: false, etc.

    ...

}
```

Or you can try use 'bean' notation rather than try to use the XML namespace 'jee...' which will be more verbose but easier to implement in Grails bean notation.

XML:

```
<bean id="simple" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/MyDataSource"/>
    <property name="jndiEnvironment">
        <props>
            <prop key="foo">bar</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Grails DSL:

```
beans {
    simple(org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean) {
        jndiName = 'jdbc/MyDataSource'
        jndiEnvironment = ["foo":"bar"]
    }

    ...
}
```

Refer to Grails documentation on "Using Spring Namespaces" also for more information [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/14.%20Grails%20and%20Spring.html).

I also [blogged](http://crontar.blogspot.com/2011/09/spring-grails-bean-builder-confusion.html) a bit about using Grails BeanBuilder DSL outside of Grails which might be helpful but Grails documentation will most likely be more helpful.